# How do I handle passport js redirects from Nuxt SSR?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, passport.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt SSR with express session and I have a passport JS redirect from the server side

```
/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account.
 */
exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  const validationErrors = [];
  if (!validator.isEmail(req.body.email)) validationErrors.push({ msg: 'Please enter a valid email address.' });
  if (!validator.isLength(req.body.password, { min: 8 })) validationErrors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 8 characters long' });
  if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) validationErrors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });

  if (validationErrors.length) {
    req.flash('errors', validationErrors);
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
  req.body.email = validator.normalizeEmail(req.body.email, { gmail_remove_dots: false });

  const user = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.' });
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }
    user.save((err) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  });
};
```

If I call the redirect method? it would reload the page and clear Vuex state right?
How do I do this redirect from passport such that Vuex state is kept intact and client page does not refresh

Comment: It seams you are using form submit for signup, you must use asynchronous signup using axios or something similar and generate positive response like `res.json({success:true})` instead of `res.redirect('/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed better to asynchronously handle form submissions to avoid page refresh as @Darius mentioned. But for completion's sake I'd like to mention that solutions do exist to persist your Vuex state, such as [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/).
It can be used to persist the state to localStorage, sessionStorage, or even cookies. It can also be used as a Nuxt plugin.